# Mongodb changing the unique key

Tags: mongodb

I have made the users email the unique key for my entire users database:

```
var usersSchema = new Schema({
    _id:              String,   // Users Unique Email address
    name:             String,   // Users name
    phone:            String,   // Users phone number
    country:          String,   // Country 
    type:             String,   // tenant/agent/manager/admin
    username:         String,   // Username for login
    password:         String,   // Password string
    trello:           Object,   // Trello auth settings
    settings:         Object,   // Settings for manager and other things
    createDate:       Number,   // Date user was created
    contactDate:      Number,   // Date user was last contacted
    activityDate:     Number    // Date of last activity on this user (update/log/etc)
});
```

So what if the user changes email address?

Is my only way to delete the record and create it again?
Or is there a smarter way?

And the users._id (email) have relations in 16 other tables.
Example the booking table

```
var bookingSchema = new Schema({
    _id:                    String,     // Unique booking ID
    user:                   String,     // User ID --> users._id
    property:               String,     // Property ID --> property._id
    checkin:                Number,     // Check in Date
    checkout:               Number      // Check out Date
});
```

One user can have a LOT of bookings

What I would do is find all records that matches the email and then do a for `(i=1 ; i<booking.length ; i++)` and then update the email of each record

Is there a smarter way to update all emails that matches using only one mongo call?

(the reason is there are so many relations, so my loop seems a bit like a very primitive way of doing it)

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's much cleaner to create a field for `email` and create an Unique Index on that.

Unfortunately still the relationship as the ones inside the Relational databases isn't supported! There are plans according to the latest talks to create this feature natively.

The best solution for you would be to think how to use the sub-documents to make things more consistent.

Comment: Ehsan it still does not solve any of my current issues :-)